# Rails form_tag in <tr></tr> tag

Tags: ruby-on-rails, erb

I have a form_tag in the last row of my table

```
<tr>
  <%= form_tag(emails_path, method: :post) do %>
    <td><%= text_field_tag 'email', nil, class: "form-control" %></td>
    <td><%= submit_tag "add", class: "btn btn-small btn-success" %></td>
  <% end %>
</tr>
```

which render the following

```
<tr>
  <form accept-charset="UTF-8" action="/emails" method="post"></form> <!-- Close here -->
  <td><input class="form-control" id="email" name="email" type="text"></td>
  <td><input class="btn btn-small btn-success" name="commit" type="submit" value="add"></td>
</tr>
```

The "add" button is not working because the form tags is not wrapping my input controls in it.

But when I try to take the form out of the table like this

```
  <%= form_tag(emails_path, method: :post) do %>
    <p><%= text_field_tag 'email', nil, class: "form-control" %></p>
    <p><%= submit_tag "add", class: "btn btn-small btn-success" %></p>
  <% end %>
```

The form render correctly and the "add" button works.

How can I do it? And I remember that it used to work....

Answer (score 6, accepted):

You can't do this.

Your form tag cannot exist there, interspersed with the markup of a table. It has to go inside a `<td>`. You're producing invalid markup, and the browser is interpreting it as best it can.

You should use your second option, with `<p>` tags, or rethink your need to have a form span multiple table cells, or wrap the *entire* table in a single `<form>`.

Comment: Thank you! I finally wrap a <table> in my <td>. Is it a good practice markup?